# Bash script for identifying users

Tags: bash, awk

I think I may have approached this problem the wrong way and I could really use a hand here. 
I'm trying to print a report to the screen using awk. I want to list the users logged in and their full names next to each user. The only way I could figure it out is below, but it only shows my own info. Can I add it into a loop somehow to achieve this or did I go about it completely wrong?

This is what I have:

```
echo "User name"  "|"  "Full name"
echo "--------------------------"
echo -n "$USER " ; awk -v user="$USER" -F":" 'user==$1{print$5}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: The environment variable `USER` would display _your_ user name.

Comment: You may be looking for the [who](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(Unix)) command, which displays a list of users who are currently logged into the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$USER` variable just contains your username.

You can pipe the `who` command to get the list of logged in users.

```
echo "User name"  "|"  "Full name"
echo "--------------------------"
who | while read username rest; do
    echo -n "$username " ; awk -v user="$username" -F":" 'user==$1{print$5}' /etc/passwd
done
```

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks, I've been racking my brain for hours for such a simple little solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you find yourself writing a loop in shell to process text, you have the wrong solution.

```
who | awk '
BEGIN { print "User name|Full name\n--------------------------" }
NR==FNR { name[$1] = $5; next }
{ print $1, name[$1] }
' FS=":" /etc/passwd FS=" " -
```

Shell is just an environment from which to call tools and it has a language to sequence those calls. The shell tool to process text is awk.